# Why do bouncing Actors in my JavaScript browser game not work?

Tags: javascript, browser, pixi.js

I want to implement a rocket flying through space, which bounces off from incoming meteroids. Currently I have implemented it by comparing the x and y position of both actors and swapping their speeds on collision. The detection of a collision and the speed swapping does work (proved by console.log), however on the screen they only sometimes bounce off.

I tried to make sure that the speed objects of the compared actors do not reference the same JavaScript object (with `cSpeedX` etc).

The game is built with Pixi JS.

*The collision detection function, executed for each actor (all meteroids and the rocket)*

```js
export const checkCollision = (current, objects) => {
    objects.forEach((o) => {
        if (current !== o) {
            const dx =
                current.x < o.x
                    ? o.x - o.width / 2 - (current.x + current.width / 2)
                    : current.x - current.width / 2 - (o.x + o.width / 2);

            const dy =
                current.y < o.y
                    ? o.y - o.height / 2 - (current.y + current.height / 2)
                    : current.y - current.height / 2 - (o.y + o.height / 2);

            if (dx < 0 && dy < 0) {
                const cSpeedX = current.speed.x;
                const cSpeedY = current.speed.y;
                const oSpeedX = o.speed.x;
                const oSpeedY = o.speed.y;

                current.speed.x = oSpeedX;
                current.speed.y = oSpeedY;
                o.speed.x = cSpeedX;
                o.speed.y = cSpeedY;
            }
        }
    });
```

*The move function implemented both on the rocket and meteroids*

```js
this.move = (delta) => {
            this.x += this.speed.x * delta;
            this.y += this.speed.y * delta;
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const checkCollision = (current, objects) => {
    objects.forEach((o) => {
        if (current !== o) {
```

You wrote also: `The collision detection function, executed for each actor (all meteroids and the rocket)`

so i suppose somewhere there is also loop like:

```
objects.forEach((o) => {
    checkCollision(o, objects);
});
```

This would mean that for every pair of objects the collision is checked twice.

Lets assume that `o1` and `o2` are some different objects, and that they collide. What will happen then? :

```
checkCollision(o1, objects); <-- swap speed between o1 and o2
...
checkCollision(o2, objects); <-- swap speed between o2 and o1
```

So speed will be swapped 2 times between them - in other words: speed of both objects will remain the same.

To investigate if this is indeed the case you can put `console.log` (or something to print id of object) like this:

```
            if (dx < 0 && dy < 0) {
                console.log('swapping speed of of objects:');
                console.log(current);
                console.log(o);
                const cSpeedX = current.speed.x;
```

Then prepare situation when 2 objects collide and check console logs.

Comment: Thank you, this was the problem!